# Maintaining state of dynamically-generated checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

I'm using jquery to dynamically create a list of checkboxes.  However, when there's an error, I need to preserve the state of the checkboxes.

I have this working, but it seems a bit kludgy: get the value from the posted form, put it into viewstate, put the value of the viewstate var into a hidden field, get the value of the hidden field in js, split it into an array, iterate thru the array comparing IDs.

In my controller:

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ... stuff ...
  }
  else
  {
    ViewData["cbHack"] = Request.Form["cb_name"];
  }
```

In my view:

```
 <%= Html.Hidden("cbHack",ViewData["cbHack"]) %>
```

And the javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#TriggerDDL option:selected").each(function() {
      $.getJSON('/controller/action/id', function(data, status) {
        var foo = '<p>';
        var selected = $('#cbHack').val().split(",");
        if (data.length > 0) {
          for (x in data) {
            var d = data[x];
            foo += "<input type='checkbox' name='cb_name' value='" + d.id + "'";
            for (var s in selected) {
              if (d.id == selected[s]) {
                foo += " checked ";
                $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
              }
            }
            foo += ">" + d.text;
            foo += "<br/>";
          }
          cb += "</p>";
          $("#DynFoo").html(foo);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

How can this be improved?

Comment: What type of error?  Validation server side or an exception thrown?

Comment: If there's a validation error, ModelState.IsValid will be false, so the value of the checkbox list will end up in ViewData.

Comment: Why do you create checkboxxes on client side? It is unnecesarry complication.